# How to refresh individual UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm having UITableView with few UITableViewCells,

Which plays Different Audio files based on their index path.

I'm showing play/pause button in UITableViewCell.

on play button click in a UITableViewCell,i wanted to reset play button state for last played cell to default(Play).

**Storing index of cell** in which the play button tapped would do the thing,but we need to reload all the UITableView,**Instead of reloading entire UITableView**,can't we **refresh/reload individual UITableViewCells?**

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks in-advance.

Comment: do not know what you want to do bt to reload table you uou can use `[self.tableView reloadData]` or  `[self.tableView beginUpdates];`

Comment: create a property in your datasource it must be some array, say `isplaying` for each of your data. Then when you play loop your datasource set `isplaying=false;` for all, and `isplaying=true;` for the current one, and then `reload` your tableview. Bingo.

Answer (score 1):

Two step:
1.find get the press row by rewrite your UITableCellView's button's action method
2.update the press row's image

Answer (score 0):

Abstract tip: When using table views have every case implemented in its **cellForRow** method, that is in its data source. After any change of state or actual data just reload the table with **reloadData**.
Work for me every time.

More detailed: In your case - have a global index var to show which row is 'playing' now. In **cellForRow** check if current and global indexes match and show the right button. 
Note, that you can also assign tag to any view (buttons also), this can be useful to know which row each button belongs to.

Comment: reloadData is a performance heavy operation which recreates all the cells from scratch. It should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @feb - If the data is changed then `reloadData` or one of its variants must be used.  Far more efficient than crashing.

Comment: I agree, but in this case the data does not change, just the state of the cell

Comment: @feb - Premature optimization is not good, as they say. Usually there is few rows in that table, so it's not that bad, especially on modern devices.
Also, there are reusable cells in case you meet performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you have IndexPath of selected cell; then you can get the cell by

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableviewObj cellForRowAtIndexPath:selIndexPath];
```

now you have reference to cell; you can change cells content. i would suggest not to change height of the cell through this process.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, when a user taps a Play button in a different cell, you want to pause the one currently playing and play the new one. The previous cell image should go back from Pause to Play.

In your code where you change Play to Pause and start playing, save an Index path of that cell. Next time Play is clicked check if you have an Index path saved, get the cell and reset the image on it. Something like this:

```
tableView:didSelectCell {
  if (lastPlayingCellPath) {
    MyCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastPlayingCellPath];
    [cell setPlayImage];
  }

  // Play Audio and change current cell image to Pause

  lastPlayingCellPath= selectedCellPath;
}
```

The above is pseudo code, but you should get the idea.

EDIT: From the comments I figured that your custom UITableViewCell subclass handles the tap event. You could fire a notification that you are starting to play. Every cell would subscribe to that event and reset the state of it's button. So you could do something like this in your subclass

```
- (instancetype)init {
  // standard init code
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willPlay) name:@"CellWillPlayNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)willPlay {
  [self setPlayImage];
}

-(void)buttonTapped {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CellWillPlayNotification" object:self];

// Do your standard handling of the tap
}
```

Comment: you understanded correctly but my cells were customised ones.. im not using any didselect cell anywhwere...just dealing with the buttons in the content view of cell

Comment: You created all cells via Storyboard and tied the Play/Pause button of each one to an Action outlet?

Comment: in story board the cell is only one...we are mananging the data Of That Cell from a sub class of uitableviewcell

Comment: **Do not** save a reference to the cell!!  Invoke the TableView's (not dataSource's) `cellForRow...` method to get a reference to the cell.

Comment: Correct, my mistake. The cell might have been reused by the time the reference is called. Index path should be saved